# How to create a mathjax rmarkdown notebook cell?

Tags: latex, r-markdown, mathjax

I would like to put mathjax in an Rmarkdown notebook. Something like this:

````
```{mathjax}
  $$
    g(x) = \sum_{k=1}^K \pi_k f_k(x; \vartheta_k)
  $$
```
````

Which would output, in stylized form:

```
g(x)=∑k=1Kπkfk(x;ϑk)
```

It doesn't seem that latex/mathjax syntax are interchangeable, though perhaps I'm wrong there?